# WUApiLib get Root category Name

Tags: c#

I'm writing a small code to get windows updates on a machine.

I got everything going fine, code below:

```
ISearchResult sResult = uSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 AND IsHidden=0");

//Count updates needed
int totalUpdates = sResult.Updates.Count;

//Here im trying to get RootCategories name, but I don't know the correct type to use to get
//that information. I can see the data I want on debugger, but I cannot figure out which type.

foreach (var s in sResult.RootCategories)
{

}
```

Here is a picture that show what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIYI5.png

So how do I get Category name ?

Answer (score 0):

Update!

I got it, to know the actual type behind the COM wrapper, use this:

```
 Debug.Write(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName([YOUR COM OBJECT]));
```

That will tell you the object type, in my case: `ICategory`

I hope it help someone else!